# How to write Unobtrusive Ajax calls in jquery with rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am currently in `rails 3.1`. I wanna achieve ajax call in jquery with out the use of form_for method.

My current page is `localhost:3000/posts/show/2` and I have a button in the page and it does not belong under any form. On click of that button, I have to send an ajax call to the `create` action in the `Comments` controller and this is the jquery code

```
    $(function(){
        $('#add_button').click(function(){
            $.post('comments/create', function(data) {
              $('.result').html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

but this didnt end in an ajax call but it was a browser call and got an error saying could not find the method in `Posts` controller. I even tried changing the url in `$.post` to `Comments.create` (fyi, I have added necessary changes in routes.rb) but still i end up getting a browser call and an error.

How can i restrict it to pure ajax call and how to access the correct url(i.e. to access action of a comments controller inside the view of a Posts controller)?

Comment: What is the reason you're avoiding a form? (You can do ajax forms quite easily.)

Comment: I am just giving an example here. I have certain use-cases which need to send such ajax calls..

Comment: Please see answer below. That should help you with all your rails 3.1 ajax needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it 'the rails way' I would suggest you read this excellent post: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

That way you'll be able to bind your code to rail's remote link code.